# Concatenating Two Values From Shared Preferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Having a little trouble figuring this one out. I have two values stored in my `Config` class as shared preferences, an email address and a URL. This will parse JSON to a ListView from my server. I'm trying to concatenate them together but it is not working.

**Config.java**

```
public class Config {

    //URL to JSON API
    public static final String GET_ORDERS_URL = "http://192.568.8.245/android/json3.php?user_email=";

    //Storing current user
    public static final String EMAIL_SHARED_PREF = "user_email";

}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Concatenated URL to JSON API
        private static final String baseurl = Config.GET_ORDERS_URL;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Fetching email from shared preferences
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String user_email = sharedPreferences.getString(Config.EMAIL_SHARED_PREF,"Not Available");

        //Concatenated JSON API URL
        String url = baseurl + user_email;

        //Initializing Toolbar
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_back);
        toolbar.setTitle(user_email);
}
```

I know `user_email` is being stored because I am calling it within `MainActivity` and setting the title of my toolbar with it. Replacing `user_email` with an actual email results in success, obviously I don't want to do that. Any idea what I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use android UrlEncoder class to make correct url

this is the best way. **Using manual concatenate can result in malformed requests.**

and also you can build URI like this

```
String uri = Uri.parse("http://...")
                .buildUpon()
                .appendQueryParameter("key", "val")
                .build().toString();
```

Comment: OK I've been working on this for the last couple of hours, trying to use the URI builder like you suggested but still get no result. Did I build it correctly or is my syntax wrong?  I've edited my original code.

Comment: OK I finally got this working after 5 hours.  I tried using the URI builder and still would like to, so any more hints on that would be great. In the meantime, I used a solution similar to what Henry suggested, and I updated the code to reflect the changes.

Comment: Sure, you helped me figure it out, I went with `Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();` etc...

Answer (score 0):

Note: the OP has applied this answer already to the code in it's question. It was meant for version 1 of the question.

The concatenation is working and results in the string:

```
"http://192.568.8.245/android/json3.php?user_email=user_email"
```

because you concatenate with the shared preferences key, not the value.

You want to concatenate with the value retrieved from shared preferences instead

```
String user_email = sharedPreferences.getString(Config.EMAIL_SHARED_PREF);
String url = Config.GET_ORDERS_URL + user_email;
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the values and call concatStrings(str1,str2);
Use something like this

```
String concatStrings(String string1,String string2){
    StringBuilder strBuilder=new StringBuilder();
    strBuilder.append(string1);
    strBuilder.append(string2);
    return  strBuilder.toString();
}
```

Comment: How is this better than the much easier `string1 + string2`?

Comment: I gave you this answer from my personal experience because sometimes while sending some data to server or so it adds unknown,invisible symbols sometimes and i don't get the desired output. But using StringBuilder always gives me desired output. It also helps if you have escape characters in any of your String.

Comment: Well, actually it does exactly the same. It is unclear to me how you arrived at the conclusion that there is a difference.

Comment: it depends on how you are using,and what you have in the strings.Well this is what i get so shared the code,may be you get the right answer but i don't.You can ignore my answer if that doesn't help you